Problems with specific case of Blackman formula for calculating input impedance
I was reading a book about basic CMOS circuits ("Analog Design Essentials", W. Sansen) and I stumbled uppon this ciruit where input impedance \$z_{in}\$ is to be calculated.

I tried using Blackman formula. I calculated \$z_{in}^{A\rightarrow 0} = R_1+(R_2\parallel \frac{1}{SC_F})\$ pretty easily. There is only one element which gives amplification \$A\$ so i am just left with 3 impedances.
The problem comes when i try calculating the Return Ratio part. 
\$RR\$ is calculated from \$-\frac{v_{in}-v_{out}}{v_t}\$ where \$v_t\$ is put instead of dependent voltage generator \$A\cdot (v_{in}-v_{out})\$.
The problem is that \$v_{in}\$ is shorted already so \$z_{in,open-circuit}\$ is the same as \$z_{in,short-circuit}\$ cuz the circuit is already shorted from the beginning when i shorted independent input source!
Finally, i get \$z_{in} = z_{in}^{A\rightarrow 0}\cdot\frac{1+1}{1+1} = \dots = \frac{R_1+R_2+R_1R_2SC_F}{1+R_2SC_F}\$ so i am at least getting the pole (\$f_2\$) right, but the zero i get is wrong \$R_1+R_2+R_1R_2SC_F=0\rightarrow f_z=\frac{R_1+R_2}{2\pi R_1R_2C_F}\$ which is not what the picture says is right so im pretty sure the problem is the already shorted input which makes \$\frac{1+z_{sc}}{1+z_{oc}}=1\$.

The whole point of calculating $Z_{in, open}$ is to not short the independent source! You must disconnect that source first, then attempt the solution by shorting/opening the input and calculating the proper loop gains. Finally, you need the feedforward impedance value, which is the input impedance with the feedback element turned off.

@a360pilot I understand that, but its really hard for me to implement it for this circuit because positive terminal of Opamp is floating when i try calculating it.
Isnt that crazy?
If i try a different method where i leave dependent sources and I cut the feedback loop, dependend source becomes dependant on itself $v_{op,minus} = A\cdot(v_{in}-v_{minus})$. I have correctly calculated like 50 circuits imput impedance from yesterday until today and I have never seen such crazy situation. If you have the time, please write a simple derivation as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Have never seen the textbook of your reference, and although most probably it gives a satisfactory explanation of the input impedance picture you stumbled upon, I hope I can present a clear and concise explanation, too. The downward slope with your red marks is a manifestation of the opamp transfer function with a single-pole roll-off behavior. This roll-off is the result of the opamp internal circuitry which is not shown in your circuit.
First, we exclude from your circuit the components which do not participate in the input impedance calculation. We replace Vin and Cc with the current source Iin:

With only three nodes in this circuit, the input impedance can be easily calculated with equations:
Iin + Icv = Vdiv / R2          # KCL at node Vdiv

Vin - Vdiv = Icf / (j·ω·Cf)    # Ohm for Cf

Vin - Vdiv = Iin·R1            # Ohm for R1

Eliminating Vdiv and Ic, we arrive at
Vin = Iin·(R1 + R2 - R1·R2·(j·ω·Cf))

and
Zin = R1 + R2 - R1·R2·(j·ω·Cf).
Thanks to the spin-off from the circuit captured in LTspice, we can simulate and have a Zin graph:

In the next step, we add the components in order to replace the ideal opamp with a slightly less ideal opamp. The single-pole opamp subcircuit is captured to model an opamp with a single pole produced by the RpCp network. The positive feedback is not closed in this drawing, and the Vout/Vin graph demonstrates a transfer function with a single-pole roll-off behavior in the simulation with this circuit:

Now, we can close the positive feedback network. The KCL/KVL equations for the circuit with positive feedback look formidable with this not-so-ideal opamp, but still amenable to symbolic calculations. Fortunately, for you to make sure that the culprit of high-frequency roll-off is the opamp frequency transfer function and not the negative feedback, you can run a simulation and have a plot closely resembling the graph from your textbook:

UPDATE on comments
Do not count poles, just take a look at an RCR (RLR) network in the T configuration excited by a current source. The voltage across the current source tends to constants at both low and high frequencies.
Getting back to the circuit with an ideal opamp, you see the RCR network in the T configuration (R1-Cf-R2), but the opposite end of capacitor Cf is connected to the opamp output. It is not a problem, because the circuit can be transformed to a circuit with the R1-Cf-R2 network connected to the opamp only at the non-inverting input, like this:

In this tranformation, I leverage the circuit linearity (all components are linear) and the ideas of circuit rearrangement inspired by the Miller theorem and the simulated inductor (gyrator) circuit. A gyrator is used to transform a load capacitance into an inductance in the circuit that works by inverting and multiplying the effect of the capacitor in an RC differentiating circuit. The Miller theorem enables a floating impedance element in the feedback network to be split into two grounded elements with corresponding impedances. I won't bore you with the truth, especially because actually I did not perform all the necessarily calculations, but just adjusted the component values for the transfer functions of both source and transformed circuits to match, benefiting from my knowledge of the transformed circuit topology.
Summing up, capacitor Cf is replaced with inductor Lf, as it is done in the active gyrator implementation; Lf is split into two inductances, one connected at input, another connected at the output of the active component (opamp), the transformation inspired by the Miller theorem. The inductance at the opamp output do not contribute to transfer fuction and can be safely omitted. The values of inductance and the voltage divider resistances are adjusted to required values in this post, but the inductance Lf and resistance R3 values can be precisely calculated to match both Vin graphs exactly.

Regardless of the pole count, the Vin tends to constant at high frequencies, and the high-frequency Vout behavior is dominated by the single-pole opamp TF:

If you enumerate the poles correctly, you will find out that their count is exactly the value that is predicted in theory.

Willy Sansen is kinda famous for doing this type of stuff - giving just an intuitive approach without explaining formula derivation too much or at all sometimes. The thing is, i think sometimes he is wrong, but i doubt myself more than him because he is Willy Sansen. Practically, I have gotten the same answer as you after a dozen more times. Thank you for explaining this circuit in great detail, but I am still confused on how he got the pole (i guess?) $f_2$ and where does it come from? If one pole comes from opamp, shouldn't it just flatten H(jf) instead of making it decrease by 20dB/dec?

@JonNezbit I've read your comment and the comments to other answer. Please notice that the functions Vout/Vin and Vout/Iin are different and their shapes can look entirely different. To help you settle your confusion, I've made an update to my answer

If you look at the impedance at the positive op-amp pin, the (+), there should not be a peak in the impedance plot and the illustrated response is misleading in my opinion. As V.V.T underlined, if you start involving the op-amp low-frequency pole, that is a different configuration and it should be highlighted somewhere.
No reason to be intimidated by the op-amp, remember it is connected to ground internally so you can simplify the circuit by a voltage source biasing the right terminal of \$C_f\$ and referenced to ground.

This is what I've done below and I applied the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my last book:

In this mode, the pole is infinite and you have one zero only. I can check theses results with a SPICE simulation using SIMetrix:

I can also, for the sake of completeness, superimpose the SPICE mag and phase over the Mathcad plot and they are rigorously identical:

As a conclusion, I don't understand where the curve comes from. Besides, the zero calculation, on my side, involves the parallel combination of the two resistances, not their sum as the book implies.

I have gotten the same parallel configuration of R1 and R2. The thing is, I doubt myself more than Willy Sansen, but I think he is wrong sometimes, especially when it comes to zeros/poles. Thanks for your explanation, but i still don't understand how he got pole (i think?) $f_2$ calculated? If there is only one pole and the pole comes from Opamp, why doesn't H(jf) flatten to 0dB/dec, but it starts decreasing by 20dB/dec as if there are 2 poles?

Well, the zero is wrong in the definition and there is no pole as confirmed by simple simulations. You remark is correct, to break the +1-slope into a -1 slope, you need two poles. You could have two poles in an op-amp (one at low freq and the second one usually after crossover, so quite high) but involving them into the definition would make the exercise extremely complicated.

In the V.V.T's answer, opamp is simulated as one pole circuit and opamp still behaves as a 2 pole circuit. Should the circuit be redrawn with $A_{opamp}\approx 1$ or is it something else that changes the topology and another pole emerges at the same place? Maybe its because i am a begginer, but i have never seen a situation where another pole emerges, effectively doubling existing opamp pole.

This would require further thoughts, but the addition of this extra pole makes things more complicated to analyze. Looks like the first pole which was infinite in the first place is brought back at lower frequencies. To analyze this circuit, you have to insert a low-pass $RC$ filter in series with my ground-referenced source B3 but calculate its new value in this unity-gain buffer. This new pole is approximate at 317 MHz. Then buffer the filter and drive capacitor $C_2$ to obtain the same curve as V.V.T.

What i have (maybe) figured out is that mine final formula for $z_{in}$ is calculated under condition $A_{opamp}\approx 1$ and that creates the pole that i have calculated ($f_2$). I have calculated that WITHOUT changing ideal opamp with one pole opamp. My guess is that, one pole (non-ideal ) opamp has its own pole + it induces a pole in my formula when  $A_{opamp}=1$ (or some low value of $A_{opamp}$) actually happens. I cannot prove that those two poles would be aligned at all, but let me know if it at least makes sense or if it is possible at all.

The thing to realize is that the low-frequency open-loop pole translates into different values when the gain is reduced (see the discussion starting page 18 of my APEC 2015 seminar) and it will be at a different position when you wire the op-amp as a follower. I recommend to start to model the voltage-follower as a simple gain of 1 but followed by the re-calculated equivalent pole. Check your calculations are ok with SPICE and then proceed with the $Z_{in}$ determination.
